# PostgreSQL: How to avoid repeating the same calculation in a materialized view?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg

Is there any way to reference a calculated column when calculating another column in a materialized view? Example - let's say I have a table that's holding a student's test scores

```
CREATE TABLE student_scores(
    student_id integer ... ,
    test_id integer ... ,
    score integer ... ,
)
```

I haven't found any way to do this and don't think there is one, but would it be possible to refer to a calculated column in the calculation of another column so I can avoid repeating calculations in a materialized view?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW student_average AS
    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS tests_taken,
        (SUM(score) / COUNT(*)) AS average_1,      -- THIS IS REPEATING THE FIRST CALCULATED COLUMN
        (SUM(score) / tests_taken) AS average_2    -- IS THIS POSSIBLE?
    FROM student_scores
    GROUP BY student_id;
```

Yes, I know I would just do `AVG(score)`. This is just the first example of what I want to do that came to mind.

Assuming there are no direct solutions, are there any practical alternate solutions to this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: no you can't use alias columns names in the same select.

Comment: Do note that a METERIALIZED VIEW has some negative aspects, like [a view, the data is not always current](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html#:~:text=a%20view%2C%20the%20data%20is%20not%20always%20current), which would be needed to be compared to the positive aspects, like [While access to the data stored in a materialized view is often much faster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html#:~:text=While%20access%20to%20the%20data%20stored%20in%20a%20materialized%20view%20is%20often%20much%20faster)

Answer (score 0):

Well not directly. Whether you should and whether it is useful is up to the user:

```
CREATE TABLE student_scores(
    student_id integer,
    test_id integer,
    score integer
)
;

INSERT INTO 
    student_scores 
VALUES 
    (1, 1, 82), (2, 1, 78), (3, 1, 86), 
    (1, 2, 83), (2, 2, 70), (3, 2, 80);

SELECT
    student_id as sid,
    COUNT(*) AS tests_taken,
    (SUM(score) / COUNT(*)) AS average_1
FROM 
    student_scores
GROUP BY 
    student_id
ORDER BY 
    student_id;

sid | tests_taken | average_1 
-----+-------------+-----------
   1 |           2 |        82
   2 |           2 |        74
   3 |           2 |        83

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.ct_fnc()
 RETURNS TABLE(sid integer, test_taken integer, avg numeric)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    tests_taken integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO tests_taken
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        student_scores
    GROUP BY student_id;

    RETURN QUERY     select
        student_id, tests_taken, (sum(score)/tests_taken)::numeric
    FROM
        student_scores
    GROUP BY
        student_id, tests_taken
    ORDER BY
        student_id;
END;
$function$
;

create materialized view st_avg as select * from ct_fnc();
SELECT 3

select * from st_avg ;
 sid | test_taken | avg 
-----+------------+-----
   1 |          2 |  82
   2 |          2 |  74
   3 |          2 |  83
```